# Azure Sphere - Quectel BG96 LTE AT Command - Azure IoT Device Provisioning Service - MQTT

Tags: mqtt, azure-iot-hub, at-command, lte, azure-sphere

I have an azure sphere application connected and pushing telemetry to Azure IoT device provisioning service with inbuilt wifi module available in MT3620 MCU.
I followed this article to achieve this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/app-development/setup-iot-hub-with-dps?tabs=cliv2beta

Now my requirement is to deploy the device in a remote location where wifi is not available, for that I chose "MikroE LtE IoT Click 2" board which uses "Quectel BG96 - LTE Cat M1/Cat NB1/EGPRS".

Now I need to connect to same Azure device provisioning service using AT commands, Quectel has provided sample AT command to connect using MQTT

```
//Configure MQTT session into SSL mode.
AT+QMTCFG=”SSL”, 0, 1, 2
OK
//If SSL authentication mode is “server authentication”, store CA certificate to UFS.
AT+QFUPL="cacert.pem",1758,100
CONNECT
<Input the cacert.pem data, the size is 1758 bytes>
+QFUPL: 1758,384a
OK
//If SSL authentication mode is “server authentication”, store CC certificate to UFS.
AT+QFUPL="client.pem",1220,100
CONNECT
<Input the client.pem data, the size is 1220 bytes>
+QFUPL: 1220,2d53
OK
//If SSL authentication mode is “server authentication”, store CK certificate to UFS.
AT+QFUPL="user_key.pem",1679,100
CONNECT
<Input the client.pem data, the size is 1679 bytes>
+QFUPL: 1679,335f
OK
//Configure CA certificate.
AT+QSSLCFG="cacert",2,"cacert.pem"
OK
//Configure CC certificate
AT+QSSLCFG="clientcert",2,"client.pem"
OK
//Configure CK certificate.
AT+QSSLCFG="clientkey",2,"user_key.pem"
OK
//Configure SSL parameters.
AT+QSSLCFG="seclevel”,2,2 //SSL authentication mode: server authentication
OK
AT+QSSLCFG="sslversion”,2,4 //SSL authentication version
OK
AT+QSSLCFG="ciphersuite”,2,0XFFFF //Cipher suite
OK
AT+QSSLCFG="ignorelocaltime",1 //Ignore the time of authentication.
OK
//Start MQTT SSL connection
AT+QMTOPEN=0, "a1zgnxur10j8ux.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",8883
OK
+QMTOPEN: 0,0
//Connect to MQTT server
AT+QMTCONN=0,"MQTT-1"
OK
+QMTCONN: 0,0,0
//Subscribe to topics.
AT+QMTSUB=0,1,"$aws/things/ MQTT-1/shadow/update/accepted",1
OK
+QMTSUB: 0,1,0,1
//Publish messages.
AT+QMTPUB=0,1,1,0,"$aws/things/MQTT-1/shadow/update/accepted"
>This is publish data from client
OK
+QMTPUB: 0,1,0
//If a client subscribes to a topic named “$aws/things/MQTT-1/shadow/update/accepted” and other 
devices publish the same topic to the server, the module will report the following information.
+QMTRECV: 0,1,"$aws/things/MQTT-1/shadow/update/accepted",“This is publish data from client”
//Disconnect a client from MQTT server.
AT+QMTDISC=0
OK
+QMTDISC: 0,0
```

How do I get CA, CC and CK Certificates for Azure Device provisioning service?

Comment: I believe you will need DigiCert Baltimore Root Certificate. See more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#tlsssl-configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you have solved this problem already, I'm facing same problem last week.

To get cc, ca, ck, you can follow instruction via [azure IoT sdk c document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/tools/CACertificates/CACertificateOverview.md)
if you use PowerShell , DO NOT using PowerShell ISE, it might got error when you enter certPassword.